# Extracting specific numeric values from long textual data (R)

Tags: r, database, web-scraping, dplyr, tidyr

I have a df of online job ads and under the *job description* column, some companies mention the required number of years for each posted job. I have been successfully able to extract the salary information from the *job description* column but I am struggling to extract the same information for the number of years of experience in a given job.
Here is a data example:

```
# #Print data example with specific columns
 dput(df[1:8,c(1,3)])
```

output:

```
structure(list(id = 1:8, description = c("Job Description *\r\n\r\nJob Title:\r\n\r\nPE Teacher\r\n\r\nSchool / Location:\r\n\r\nISG Jubail\r\n\r\nSchool / Department:\r\n\r\nMiddle/High\r\n\r\nSubjects:\r\n\r\nPhysical Education\r\n\r\nJob Status:\r\n\r\nFull-time\r\n\r\nSalary Code:\r\n\r\nTeacher\r\n\r\nWork Days / Hours:\r\n\r\n191 days @ 8 hours per day\r\n\r\nEligible Applicants:\r\n\r\nSaudi National, Dependent\r\n\r\nPosition Start Date:\r\n\r\n15 August 2023\r\n\r\nApplication Deadline:\r\n\r\nUntil filled\r\n\r\nReports to:\r\n\r\nBrent Wingers, Principal\r\n\r\nRequisition Number:\r\n\r\n05-2324-050\r\n\r\nSummary\r\n\r\nISG Jubail seeks a dynamic Physical Education (PE) teacher with a passion for\r\ninvolving students in fitness, sport, and health. The ideal candidate will\r\nhave experience inspiring students to live active and healthy lives. This\r\nperson would demonstrate a commitment to a well-rounded and flexible PE\r\nprogram that encompasses multiple age, grade, and experience levels. ISG\r\nJubail has a strong sense of community. The successful candidate would be\r\ncommitted to contributing to the whole school community beyond the confines of\r\nthe PE program. The ideal candidate would be eager to engage in collaboration\r\naround our mission: We inspire innovation and compassionate action.\r\n\r\nJob Duties\r\n\r\nThe successful candidate will be able to effectively:\r\n\r\n* Demonstrate commitment to the safety and security of children and young people (child protection)\r\n* Collaborate around meeting our mission: We inspire innovation and compassionate action\r\n* Communicate and collaborate in a professional manner\r\n* Commit to continual professional learning\r\n* Plan meaningful assessment opportunities\r\n* Drive learning through assessment and feedback\r\n* Reflect on assessment goals and targets\r\n* Plan and deliver effective and meaningful learning opportunities\r\n* Know and respond to the needs of all students\r\n* Promote agency and innovation in the learning process\r\n* Foster compassion and build relationships amongst all the ISG community\r\n* Exhibit effective and positive classroom management\r\n* Contribute to student growth and collaboration\r\n* Contribute to the after-school activities program and to the wider ISG Jubail community\r\n* Effectively assess and report on student academic achievement and learning dispositions\r\n* Espouse creativity and passion in and out of the classroom\r\n\r\nSpecifically with regards to PE, the successful candidate will be able to\r\neffectively:\r\n\r\n* Inspire students to live healthy, active lifestyles\r\n* Build and lead a balanced PE program that allows for agency in individual and team settings\r\n* Contribute to the creation and revision of the PE curriculum\r\n* Coordinate / coach formal and informal athletic and after-school opportunities\r\n\r\nQualifications and Knowledge\r\n\r\nThe candidate must have:\r\n\r\n* Minimum of Bachelor's degree in a related field of study\r\n\r\nThe ideal candidate will have:\r\n\r\n* Current certification/licensure to teach PE\r\n* An advanced degree in a related field of study\r\n* Knowledge of the SHAPE Standards\r\n* Knowledge of Understanding by Design (UbD) principles\r\n\r\nExperience and Skills\r\n\r\nThe ideal candidate will have:\r\n\r\nExperience\r\n\r\n* Teaching PE at the elementary school level in an international context\r\n* Leading and inspiring elementary students to be active and healthy\r\n* Organizing events and competitions\r\n* Documenting curriculum according to Understanding by Design (UbD) principles\r\n* Designing programs based on the SHAPE Standards\r\n* Collaborating in a professional setting with large and small groups of colleagues\r\n* Leading groups of students and faculty\r\n\r\nSkills & Dispositions\r\n\r\n* Positive and compassionate outlook\r\n* Open-mindedness and flexibility\r\n* A proactive approach and ability to take initiative\r\n* Desire to engage in meaningful collaboration", 
"مطلوب للتعيين فوراً محاسب فرع \r\nومشرف فروع مالي واداري لمجموعة طبية بالرياض\r\n\r\nخبرة جيدة بالحسابات وان يتمتع بشخصية قيادية تؤهله لقيادة فريق\r\n\r\nيفضل ان يكون خبرة بالمجمعات او المراكز الطبية\r\n\r\nخبرة لا تقل عن 5 سنوات\r\n\r\nالرجاء ارسال السيرة الذاتية على البريد الالكتروني بعنوان الوظيفة المتقدم لها \r\nفضلاً يكون الجاهزية لحضور المقابلة خلال الأيام القليلة القادمة \r\njob4all90@gmail.com\r\n\r\nJob Type: Full-time\r\n\r\nSalary: ﷼5,000.00 - ﷼8,500.00 per month\r\n\r\nAbility to commute/relocate:\r\n\r\n* الرياض: Reliably commute or planning to relocate before starting work (Required)", 
"RISAL\r\n\r\nWestern Province, Saudi Arabia\r\n\r\nPosted a day ago\r\n\r\nExpires in a month\r\n\r\nJob Description\r\n\r\nResponsible for supervising the Dewatering project; Supervising the\r\ndewatering system to ensure water levels remain as required in a project\r\nenvironment. perform all aspects of the position in a safe, cost-effective,\r\nand productive manner while continuously aligning daily functions to reflect\r\nDewatering Logistics values.\r\n\r\n* Supervising all maintenance activities of the dewatering infrastructure including well points, header pipes, dewatering and surface pumps, piping,\r\n* General understanding of construction operations, as well as a good understanding of Dewatering and maintenance operations.\r\n* Support in investigating, analyzing, the documentation of accidents, injuries, and equipment damage and recommend prevention strategies as necessary.\r\n* Work with the project manager to schedule upcoming projects. Assist the Technical Services Department with determining the specifications of the equipment.\r\n* Works closely with the manager to schedule equipment repairs and replacements to maximize equipment utilization and minimize downtime.\r\n* Must be able to design a dewatering network based on soil permeability report.\r\n\r\nSkills\r\n\r\n* Good mechanical background.\r\n* Must be a leader\r\n* Ability to work with others in a team environment.\r\n* Good verbal, written, analytical, and persuasive skills\r\n* Good administrative, organizational, and technical writing skills\r\n* Good knowledge in utilizing word processing, spreadsheet, database, and presentation software.\r\n\r\nEducation\r\n\r\nHydrology or Mechanical\r\n\r\nJob Details\r\n\r\nJob Location\r\n\r\nWestern Province, Saudi Arabia\r\n\r\nCompany Industry\r\n\r\nOther Business Support Services\r\n\r\nCompany Type\r\n\r\nEmployer (Private Sector)\r\n\r\nJob Role\r\n\r\nOther\r\n\r\nJoining Date\r\n\r\n2023-04-02\r\n\r\nEmployment Status\r\n\r\nFull time\r\n\r\nNumber of Vacancies\r\n\r\n1\r\n\r\nPreferred Candidate\r\n\r\nCareer Level\r\n\r\nMid Career\r\n\r\nYears of Experience\r\n\r\nMin: 2 Max: 20\r\n\r\nDegree\r\n\r\nDiploma\r\n\r\nJob Details\r\n\r\nJob Location\r\n\r\nWestern Province, Saudi Arabia\r\n\r\nCompany Industry\r\n\r\nOther Business Support Services\r\n\r\nCompany Type\r\n\r\nEmployer (Private Sector)\r\n\r\nJob Role\r\n\r\nOther\r\n\r\nJoining Date\r\n\r\n2023-04-02\r\n\r\nEmployment Status\r\n\r\nFull time\r\n\r\nNumber of Vacancies\r\n\r\n1", 
"The ideal candidate will lead the account development and penetration strategy\r\nfor assigned customers or regions. They should be skilled at building and\r\nmaintaining relationships with clients and work to provide exceptional\r\ncustomer service to clients.\r\n\r\nResponsibilities\r\n\r\nManage a portfolio of accounts\r\n\r\nDevelop positive relationship with clients\r\n\r\nManage a number of accounts for long term success.\r\n\r\nCommunicate and deal with customer needs quickly.\r\n\r\nGenerate new business using existing and potential customer networks.\r\n\r\nSolve problems and provide solutions to customers in a timely manner.\r\n\r\nSubmit periodic reports on the status of accounts and transactions.\r\n\r\nSelect, set and track sales account targets in line with organization goals.\r\n\r\nSuggest actions to improve sales performance and identify growth\r\nopportunities.\r\n\r\nBuilding strong relationships with government agencies, ministries and private\r\ncompanies\r\n\r\nQualifications\r\n\r\n* Bachelor's degree or equivalent experience\r\n* Experience as a Sales Manager\r\n* 2 years experience in IT companies\r\n\r\nJob Type: Full-time\r\n\r\nSalary: ﷼15,000.00 - ﷼20,000.00 per month\r\n\r\nAbility to commute/relocate:\r\n\r\n* Riyadh: Reliably commute or planning to relocate before starting work (Required)", 
"Detailed Job Description:\r\n\r\n* Creating a Sales Action Plan to achieve the target\r\n* Manage the team to execute on plans and achieve targets\r\n* Carry out Performance reviews, and managing performance.\r\n* Optimise lead generation, qualification, enquiry handling, solutioning, and pricing processes to maximise business and minimise risks.\r\n* Plan Resources - including manpower for optimum results and future growth\r\n* Maintaining positive WIN-WIN relationships with Key consultants, OEMs, partners and third party SMEs to foster collaboration and enable complex projects.\r\n* Drive win-win deals, and get the best value and preferred terms from customers\r\n* Product Focus - Custom fencing, gabions, OEM products, larger Permavoid projects, ANS Global, PIDS, Data Centre projects.\r\n\r\nJob Type: Full-time\r\n\r\nSalary: ﷼10,000.00 - ﷼15,000.00 per month\r\n\r\nAbility to commute/relocate:\r\n\r\n* Jeddah: Reliably commute or willing to relocate with an employer-provided relocation package (Required)\r\n\r\nApplication Question(s):\r\n\r\n* Are you willing to relocate to Jeddah ?\r\n* Are you a Engineer?\r\n* How many Years of Experience you have in Sales?\r\n* Can you Speak Arabic?\r\n* Do you have experience in Selling products related to Electronic Security Systems or products?\r\n\r\nEducation:\r\n\r\n* Bachelor's (Preferred)\r\n\r\nExperience:\r\n\r\n* min: 3 years (Preferred)\r\n\r\nLanguage:\r\n\r\n* English, Arabic (Preferred)\r\n\r\nWillingness to travel:\r\n\r\n* 75% (Preferred)\r\n\r\nSpeak with the employer \r\n+91 8879810640", 
"Job Number 23052519 \r\nJob Category Housekeeping & Laundry \r\nLocation Four Points by Sheraton Riyadh Khaldia, Imam Faisal Bin Turki\r\nStreet, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia, Saudi Arabia VIEW ON MAP \r\nSchedule Full-Time \r\nLocated Remotely? N \r\nRelocation? N \r\nPosition Type Management\r\n\r\nJOB SUMMARY\r\n\r\nEntry level management position that focuses on supporting the day-to-day\r\nactivities in Housekeeping, Recreation/Health Club and Laundry, if applicable.\r\nPosition works with employees to clean and maintain guestrooms and public\r\nspace. Completes inspections and holds people accountable for corrective\r\naction. Position assists in ensuring guest and employee satisfaction while\r\nmaintaining the operating budget.\r\n\r\nCANDIDATE PROFILE\r\n\r\nEducation and Experience\r\n\r\n* High school diploma or GED; 1 year experience in the housekeeping or related professional area.\r\n\r\nOR\r\n\r\n* 2-year degree from an accredited university in Hotel and Restaurant Management, Hospitality, Business Administration, or related major; no work experience required.\r\n\r\nCORE WORK ACTIVITIES\r\n\r\nManaging Housekeeping Operations and Budgets\r\n\r\n* Ensures knowledge and understanding of OSHA regulations are up to date.\r\n* Oversees all lost and found procedures.\r\n* Obtains list of rooms to be cleaned immediately and list of prospective check-outs or discharges to prepare work assignments.\r\n* Inventories stock to ensure adequate supplies.\r\n* Ensures guest room status is communicated to the Front Desk in a timely and efficient manner.\r\n* Works effectively with the Engineering department on guest room maintenance needs.\r\n* Understands and complies with loss prevention policies and procedures.\r\n* Ensures all employees have proper supplies, equipment and uniforms.\r\n* Assists in supervising an effective inspection program for all guestrooms and public space.\r\n* Manages linen inventory and guest supplies and assists in the ordering of supplies as necessary.\r\n* Supervises Housekeeping and all related areas in the absence of the Director of Services or Housekeeping Manager.\r\n* Observes service behaviors of employees and provides feedback to individuals; continuously strives to improve service performance.\r\n\r\nEnsuring Exceptional Customer Service\r\n\r\n* Handles guest problems and complaints seeking assistance from supervisor as necessary.\r\n* Assists in the review of comment cards and guest satisfaction results with employees.\r\n* Sets a positive example for guest relations.\r\n\r\nMarriott International is an equal opportunity employer. We believe in hiring\r\na diverse workforce and sustaining an inclusive, people-first culture. We are\r\ncommitted to non-discrimination on any protected basis, such as disability and\r\nveteran status, or any other basis covered under applicable law.  \r\n\r\nWhere timeless classics are woven with modern details. Where business meets\r\npleasure. Where even when you're global, you can experience the local.\r\nDesigned for the independent traveler seeking balance, there's Four Points.", 
"Job Description\r\n\r\nJob title:\r\n\r\nQuality Manager\r\n\r\nLocation:\r\n\r\nRiyadh, Saudi Arabia\r\n\r\nTerms:\r\n\r\nFull time\r\n\r\nSalary/rate:\r\n\r\nRequirements:\r\n\r\nSaudi Citizen\r\n\r\nAbout us:\r\n\r\nMastery House Co. is a Limited Liability Company and well known as System\r\nIntegrator Company that organized and existing under the laws of the Kingdom\r\nof Saudi Arabia having its principal place of business at Riyadh. Since its\r\nfoundation in 2014, Mastery House has played a significant role both in the\r\nfield of general contracting and telecommunications and best practices in ICT\r\nsystems and infrastructure across the Kingdom.\r\n\r\nAbout the role:\r\n\r\nWe are looking for a quality engineer to monitor and improve the quality of\r\nour operational processes and outputs. The quality engineer's responsibilities\r\ninclude designing quality standards, inspecting materials, equipment,\r\nprocesses, and products, developing quality control systems, and determining\r\ncorrective actions. You will also work with managers and supervisors to\r\nimplement quality measures.\r\n\r\nA successful quality engineer should have excellent troubleshooting skills and\r\nbe able to ensure that processes and products consistently meet established\r\nquality standards.\r\n\r\nResponsibilities:\r\n\r\n* Developing and implementing quality standards.\r\n* Developing and implementing quality control systems.\r\n* Monitoring and analysing quality performance.\r\n* Inspecting and testing materials, equipment, processes, and products to ensure quality specifications are met.\r\n* Collaborating with operations managers to develop and implement controls and improvements.\r\n* Ensuring that workflows, processes, and products comply with safety regulations.\r\n* Investigating and troubleshooting product or production issues.\r\n* Developing corrective actions, solutions, and improvements.\r\n* Reviewing codes, specifications, and processes.\r\n\r\nCandidate requirements:\r\n* Degree in quality, industrial, or mechanical engineering.\r\n* ASQ certification preferred.\r\n* 2+ years of experience in quality engineering, quality assurance, or a similar role.\r\n* Experience coding and using QA software tools and processes.\r\n* Strong communication and interpersonal skills.\r\n* Strong analytical and problem-solving skills.\r\n* Excellent project management skills.\r\n\r\nنوع الوظيفة: دوام كامل\r\n\r\nالتعليم:\r\n\r\n* بكالوريوس (مفضل)", 
"We are looking for a \" Approval Officer \" to join a \r\n\r\nSupportive Healthcare And Health Insurance * company in Saudi Arabia.\r\n\r\nThe location work in Riyadh OR Jeddah OR Al Madina .\r\n\r\nWhat your Responsibilities :\r\n\r\n* A Medical Approval Officer's primary responsibility is to respond to online requests and inquiries from our service providers (Hospitals, Clinics, and Pharmacies) by following standard scripts and procedures.\r\n* He is in charge of providing online approvals to our service providers for eligible services.\r\n* The incumbent is also accountable for ensuring that all cases are resolved within predetermined timeframes and with the highest levels of customer service.\r\n* The Doctor will also record details of messages, conversations, and actions taken in order to follow up and take corrective action as needed.\r\n\r\nWhat are the requirements and qualifications required for the job:\r\n\r\n* 1 to 5 Years experience in Approval Officer .\r\n* Bachelor's degree.\r\n* Advance in English .\r\n* Very Good problem-solving abilities.\r\n* Very Good in MS Office.\r\n* Very Good in Operation System.\r\n* Excellent analytical, communication, and decision-making skills are essential , organization, Familiarity with relevant regulations, policies, and procedures may be necessary."
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Below is the function that worked well to extract the salary information but not with the years of experience. Ideally, I would like to have a new numeric column *yrs_experience* for each job ad/row where this is mentioned.
The code works without errors but it's producing NA values. Here is the output after running the code below:

```
structure(list(experience = c(" ", "سنوات\r", " ", " ", 
" ", " ", " ", " "), experience_extraction = structure(c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), dim = c(8L, 1L))), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
tag="years"
experience_finder = function(string){
  
  experience = c(" ")
  string=tolower(string)
  split_string = strsplit(string, split = " |\n")
  split_string = split_string[[1]]
  
  for(i in 1:length(split_string)) {
    letter=split_string[i]
    if(str_detect(letter,tag)) {experience = split_string[i]}
      }
  return(experience)
}
job_posts$experience=NA
for(n in 1:length(job_posts$description)){
  job_posts$experience[n] <- experience_finder(job_posts$description[n])
}
```

## Extracting numeric values from the string "experience" column

```
job_posts <- 
job_posts %>% mutate(experience_extraction = str_match(experience, pattern = '[0-9,\\.]+'))
```

## Converting the yrs_experience variable from string to numeric

```
job_posts <- 
job_posts %>% mutate(yrs_experience = gsub(",","",experience_extraction)) 
job_posts$yrs_experience <- as.vector(job_posts$yrs_experience) %>% as.numeric()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do the whole thing in a dplyr pipeline without the loop.  Here's the example using your data.  Here, you search for some number of digits and then any number of spaces and plus signs (sometimes the requirement is something like 2+ years), you extract the digits if the string matches and then turn it into numeric which will turn everything that didn't have a match into an `NA` (though R will give you warning that some values were coerced to `NA`, which is fine).

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
job_posts <- structure(list(id = 1:8, description = c("Job Description *\r\n\r\nJob Title:\r\n\r\nPE Teacher\r\n\r\nSchool / Location:\r\n\r\nISG Jubail\r\n\r\nSchool / Department:\r\n\r\nMiddle/High\r\n\r\nSubjects:\r\n\r\nPhysical Education\r\n\r\nJob Status:\r\n\r\nFull-time\r\n\r\nSalary Code:\r\n\r\nTeacher\r\n\r\nWork Days / Hours:\r\n\r\n191 days @ 8 hours per day\r\n\r\nEligible Applicants:\r\n\r\nSaudi National, Dependent\r\n\r\nPosition Start Date:\r\n\r\n15 August 2023\r\n\r\nApplication Deadline:\r\n\r\nUntil filled\r\n\r\nReports to:\r\n\r\nBrent Wingers, Principal\r\n\r\nRequisition Number:\r\n\r\n05-2324-050\r\n\r\nSummary\r\n\r\nISG Jubail seeks a dynamic Physical Education (PE) teacher with a passion for\r\ninvolving students in fitness, sport, and health. The ideal candidate will\r\nhave experience inspiring students to live active and healthy lives. This\r\nperson would demonstrate a commitment to a well-rounded and flexible PE\r\nprogram that encompasses multiple age, grade, and experience levels. ISG\r\nJubail has a strong sense of community. The successful candidate would be\r\ncommitted to contributing to the whole school community beyond the confines of\r\nthe PE program. The ideal candidate would be eager to engage in collaboration\r\naround our mission: We inspire innovation and compassionate action.\r\n\r\nJob Duties\r\n\r\nThe successful candidate will be able to effectively:\r\n\r\n* Demonstrate commitment to the safety and security of children and young people (child protection)\r\n* Collaborate around meeting our mission: We inspire innovation and compassionate action\r\n* Communicate and collaborate in a professional manner\r\n* Commit to continual professional learning\r\n* Plan meaningful assessment opportunities\r\n* Drive learning through assessment and feedback\r\n* Reflect on assessment goals and targets\r\n* Plan and deliver effective and meaningful learning opportunities\r\n* Know and respond to the needs of all students\r\n* Promote agency and innovation in the learning process\r\n* Foster compassion and build relationships amongst all the ISG community\r\n* Exhibit effective and positive classroom management\r\n* Contribute to student growth and collaboration\r\n* Contribute to the after-school activities program and to the wider ISG Jubail community\r\n* Effectively assess and report on student academic achievement and learning dispositions\r\n* Espouse creativity and passion in and out of the classroom\r\n\r\nSpecifically with regards to PE, the successful candidate will be able to\r\neffectively:\r\n\r\n* Inspire students to live healthy, active lifestyles\r\n* Build and lead a balanced PE program that allows for agency in individual and team settings\r\n* Contribute to the creation and revision of the PE curriculum\r\n* Coordinate / coach formal and informal athletic and after-school opportunities\r\n\r\nQualifications and Knowledge\r\n\r\nThe candidate must have:\r\n\r\n* Minimum of Bachelor's degree in a related field of study\r\n\r\nThe ideal candidate will have:\r\n\r\n* Current certification/licensure to teach PE\r\n* An advanced degree in a related field of study\r\n* Knowledge of the SHAPE Standards\r\n* Knowledge of Understanding by Design (UbD) principles\r\n\r\nExperience and Skills\r\n\r\nThe ideal candidate will have:\r\n\r\nExperience\r\n\r\n* Teaching PE at the elementary school level in an international context\r\n* Leading and inspiring elementary students to be active and healthy\r\n* Organizing events and competitions\r\n* Documenting curriculum according to Understanding by Design (UbD) principles\r\n* Designing programs based on the SHAPE Standards\r\n* Collaborating in a professional setting with large and small groups of colleagues\r\n* Leading groups of students and faculty\r\n\r\nSkills & Dispositions\r\n\r\n* Positive and compassionate outlook\r\n* Open-mindedness and flexibility\r\n* A proactive approach and ability to take initiative\r\n* Desire to engage in meaningful collaboration", 
                                                      "مطلوب للتعيين فوراً محاسب فرع \r\nومشرف فروع مالي واداري لمجموعة طبية بالرياض\r\n\r\nخبرة جيدة بالحسابات وان يتمتع بشخصية قيادية تؤهله لقيادة فريق\r\n\r\nيفضل ان يكون خبرة بالمجمعات او المراكز الطبية\r\n\r\nخبرة لا تقل عن 5 سنوات\r\n\r\nالرجاء ارسال السيرة الذاتية على البريد الالكتروني بعنوان الوظيفة المتقدم لها \r\nفضلاً يكون الجاهزية لحضور المقابلة خلال الأيام القليلة القادمة \r\njob4all90@gmail.com\r\n\r\nJob Type: Full-time\r\n\r\nSalary: ﷼5,000.00 - ﷼8,500.00 per month\r\n\r\nAbility to commute/relocate:\r\n\r\n* الرياض: Reliably commute or planning to relocate before starting work (Required)", 
                                                      "RISAL\r\n\r\nWestern Province, Saudi Arabia\r\n\r\nPosted a day ago\r\n\r\nExpires in a month\r\n\r\nJob Description\r\n\r\nResponsible for supervising the Dewatering project; Supervising the\r\ndewatering system to ensure water levels remain as required in a project\r\nenvironment. perform all aspects of the position in a safe, cost-effective,\r\nand productive manner while continuously aligning daily functions to reflect\r\nDewatering Logistics values.\r\n\r\n* Supervising all maintenance activities of the dewatering infrastructure including well points, header pipes, dewatering and surface pumps, piping,\r\n* General understanding of construction operations, as well as a good understanding of Dewatering and maintenance operations.\r\n* Support in investigating, analyzing, the documentation of accidents, injuries, and equipment damage and recommend prevention strategies as necessary.\r\n* Work with the project manager to schedule upcoming projects. Assist the Technical Services Department with determining the specifications of the equipment.\r\n* Works closely with the manager to schedule equipment repairs and replacements to maximize equipment utilization and minimize downtime.\r\n* Must be able to design a dewatering network based on soil permeability report.\r\n\r\nSkills\r\n\r\n* Good mechanical background.\r\n* Must be a leader\r\n* Ability to work with others in a team environment.\r\n* Good verbal, written, analytical, and persuasive skills\r\n* Good administrative, organizational, and technical writing skills\r\n* Good knowledge in utilizing word processing, spreadsheet, database, and presentation software.\r\n\r\nEducation\r\n\r\nHydrology or Mechanical\r\n\r\nJob Details\r\n\r\nJob Location\r\n\r\nWestern Province, Saudi Arabia\r\n\r\nCompany Industry\r\n\r\nOther Business Support Services\r\n\r\nCompany Type\r\n\r\nEmployer (Private Sector)\r\n\r\nJob Role\r\n\r\nOther\r\n\r\nJoining Date\r\n\r\n2023-04-02\r\n\r\nEmployment Status\r\n\r\nFull time\r\n\r\nNumber of Vacancies\r\n\r\n1\r\n\r\nPreferred Candidate\r\n\r\nCareer Level\r\n\r\nMid Career\r\n\r\nYears of Experience\r\n\r\nMin: 2 Max: 20\r\n\r\nDegree\r\n\r\nDiploma\r\n\r\nJob Details\r\n\r\nJob Location\r\n\r\nWestern Province, Saudi Arabia\r\n\r\nCompany Industry\r\n\r\nOther Business Support Services\r\n\r\nCompany Type\r\n\r\nEmployer (Private Sector)\r\n\r\nJob Role\r\n\r\nOther\r\n\r\nJoining Date\r\n\r\n2023-04-02\r\n\r\nEmployment Status\r\n\r\nFull time\r\n\r\nNumber of Vacancies\r\n\r\n1", 
                                                      "The ideal candidate will lead the account development and penetration strategy\r\nfor assigned customers or regions. They should be skilled at building and\r\nmaintaining relationships with clients and work to provide exceptional\r\ncustomer service to clients.\r\n\r\nResponsibilities\r\n\r\nManage a portfolio of accounts\r\n\r\nDevelop positive relationship with clients\r\n\r\nManage a number of accounts for long term success.\r\n\r\nCommunicate and deal with customer needs quickly.\r\n\r\nGenerate new business using existing and potential customer networks.\r\n\r\nSolve problems and provide solutions to customers in a timely manner.\r\n\r\nSubmit periodic reports on the status of accounts and transactions.\r\n\r\nSelect, set and track sales account targets in line with organization goals.\r\n\r\nSuggest actions to improve sales performance and identify growth\r\nopportunities.\r\n\r\nBuilding strong relationships with government agencies, ministries and private\r\ncompanies\r\n\r\nQualifications\r\n\r\n* Bachelor's degree or equivalent experience\r\n* Experience as a Sales Manager\r\n* 2 years experience in IT companies\r\n\r\nJob Type: Full-time\r\n\r\nSalary: ﷼15,000.00 - ﷼20,000.00 per month\r\n\r\nAbility to commute/relocate:\r\n\r\n* Riyadh: Reliably commute or planning to relocate before starting work (Required)", 
                                                      "Detailed Job Description:\r\n\r\n* Creating a Sales Action Plan to achieve the target\r\n* Manage the team to execute on plans and achieve targets\r\n* Carry out Performance reviews, and managing performance.\r\n* Optimise lead generation, qualification, enquiry handling, solutioning, and pricing processes to maximise business and minimise risks.\r\n* Plan Resources - including manpower for optimum results and future growth\r\n* Maintaining positive WIN-WIN relationships with Key consultants, OEMs, partners and third party SMEs to foster collaboration and enable complex projects.\r\n* Drive win-win deals, and get the best value and preferred terms from customers\r\n* Product Focus - Custom fencing, gabions, OEM products, larger Permavoid projects, ANS Global, PIDS, Data Centre projects.\r\n\r\nJob Type: Full-time\r\n\r\nSalary: ﷼10,000.00 - ﷼15,000.00 per month\r\n\r\nAbility to commute/relocate:\r\n\r\n* Jeddah: Reliably commute or willing to relocate with an employer-provided relocation package (Required)\r\n\r\nApplication Question(s):\r\n\r\n* Are you willing to relocate to Jeddah ?\r\n* Are you a Engineer?\r\n* How many Years of Experience you have in Sales?\r\n* Can you Speak Arabic?\r\n* Do you have experience in Selling products related to Electronic Security Systems or products?\r\n\r\nEducation:\r\n\r\n* Bachelor's (Preferred)\r\n\r\nExperience:\r\n\r\n* min: 3 years (Preferred)\r\n\r\nLanguage:\r\n\r\n* English, Arabic (Preferred)\r\n\r\nWillingness to travel:\r\n\r\n* 75% (Preferred)\r\n\r\nSpeak with the employer \r\n+91 8879810640", 
                                                      "Job Number 23052519 \r\nJob Category Housekeeping & Laundry \r\nLocation Four Points by Sheraton Riyadh Khaldia, Imam Faisal Bin Turki\r\nStreet, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia, Saudi Arabia VIEW ON MAP \r\nSchedule Full-Time \r\nLocated Remotely? N \r\nRelocation? N \r\nPosition Type Management\r\n\r\nJOB SUMMARY\r\n\r\nEntry level management position that focuses on supporting the day-to-day\r\nactivities in Housekeeping, Recreation/Health Club and Laundry, if applicable.\r\nPosition works with employees to clean and maintain guestrooms and public\r\nspace. Completes inspections and holds people accountable for corrective\r\naction. Position assists in ensuring guest and employee satisfaction while\r\nmaintaining the operating budget.\r\n\r\nCANDIDATE PROFILE\r\n\r\nEducation and Experience\r\n\r\n* High school diploma or GED; 1 year experience in the housekeeping or related professional area.\r\n\r\nOR\r\n\r\n* 2-year degree from an accredited university in Hotel and Restaurant Management, Hospitality, Business Administration, or related major; no work experience required.\r\n\r\nCORE WORK ACTIVITIES\r\n\r\nManaging Housekeeping Operations and Budgets\r\n\r\n* Ensures knowledge and understanding of OSHA regulations are up to date.\r\n* Oversees all lost and found procedures.\r\n* Obtains list of rooms to be cleaned immediately and list of prospective check-outs or discharges to prepare work assignments.\r\n* Inventories stock to ensure adequate supplies.\r\n* Ensures guest room status is communicated to the Front Desk in a timely and efficient manner.\r\n* Works effectively with the Engineering department on guest room maintenance needs.\r\n* Understands and complies with loss prevention policies and procedures.\r\n* Ensures all employees have proper supplies, equipment and uniforms.\r\n* Assists in supervising an effective inspection program for all guestrooms and public space.\r\n* Manages linen inventory and guest supplies and assists in the ordering of supplies as necessary.\r\n* Supervises Housekeeping and all related areas in the absence of the Director of Services or Housekeeping Manager.\r\n* Observes service behaviors of employees and provides feedback to individuals; continuously strives to improve service performance.\r\n\r\nEnsuring Exceptional Customer Service\r\n\r\n* Handles guest problems and complaints seeking assistance from supervisor as necessary.\r\n* Assists in the review of comment cards and guest satisfaction results with employees.\r\n* Sets a positive example for guest relations.\r\n\r\nMarriott International is an equal opportunity employer. We believe in hiring\r\na diverse workforce and sustaining an inclusive, people-first culture. We are\r\ncommitted to non-discrimination on any protected basis, such as disability and\r\nveteran status, or any other basis covered under applicable law.  \r\n\r\nWhere timeless classics are woven with modern details. Where business meets\r\npleasure. Where even when you're global, you can experience the local.\r\nDesigned for the independent traveler seeking balance, there's Four Points.", 
                                                      "Job Description\r\n\r\nJob title:\r\n\r\nQuality Manager\r\n\r\nLocation:\r\n\r\nRiyadh, Saudi Arabia\r\n\r\nTerms:\r\n\r\nFull time\r\n\r\nSalary/rate:\r\n\r\nRequirements:\r\n\r\nSaudi Citizen\r\n\r\nAbout us:\r\n\r\nMastery House Co. is a Limited Liability Company and well known as System\r\nIntegrator Company that organized and existing under the laws of the Kingdom\r\nof Saudi Arabia having its principal place of business at Riyadh. Since its\r\nfoundation in 2014, Mastery House has played a significant role both in the\r\nfield of general contracting and telecommunications and best practices in ICT\r\nsystems and infrastructure across the Kingdom.\r\n\r\nAbout the role:\r\n\r\nWe are looking for a quality engineer to monitor and improve the quality of\r\nour operational processes and outputs. The quality engineer's responsibilities\r\ninclude designing quality standards, inspecting materials, equipment,\r\nprocesses, and products, developing quality control systems, and determining\r\ncorrective actions. You will also work with managers and supervisors to\r\nimplement quality measures.\r\n\r\nA successful quality engineer should have excellent troubleshooting skills and\r\nbe able to ensure that processes and products consistently meet established\r\nquality standards.\r\n\r\nResponsibilities:\r\n\r\n* Developing and implementing quality standards.\r\n* Developing and implementing quality control systems.\r\n* Monitoring and analysing quality performance.\r\n* Inspecting and testing materials, equipment, processes, and products to ensure quality specifications are met.\r\n* Collaborating with operations managers to develop and implement controls and improvements.\r\n* Ensuring that workflows, processes, and products comply with safety regulations.\r\n* Investigating and troubleshooting product or production issues.\r\n* Developing corrective actions, solutions, and improvements.\r\n* Reviewing codes, specifications, and processes.\r\n\r\nCandidate requirements:\r\n* Degree in quality, industrial, or mechanical engineering.\r\n* ASQ certification preferred.\r\n* 2+ years of experience in quality engineering, quality assurance, or a similar role.\r\n* Experience coding and using QA software tools and processes.\r\n* Strong communication and interpersonal skills.\r\n* Strong analytical and problem-solving skills.\r\n* Excellent project management skills.\r\n\r\nنوع الوظيفة: دوام كامل\r\n\r\nالتعليم:\r\n\r\n* بكالوريوس (مفضل)", 
                                                      "We are looking for a \" Approval Officer \" to join a \r\n\r\nSupportive Healthcare And Health Insurance * company in Saudi Arabia.\r\n\r\nThe location work in Riyadh OR Jeddah OR Al Madina .\r\n\r\nWhat your Responsibilities :\r\n\r\n* A Medical Approval Officer's primary responsibility is to respond to online requests and inquiries from our service providers (Hospitals, Clinics, and Pharmacies) by following standard scripts and procedures.\r\n* He is in charge of providing online approvals to our service providers for eligible services.\r\n* The incumbent is also accountable for ensuring that all cases are resolved within predetermined timeframes and with the highest levels of customer service.\r\n* The Doctor will also record details of messages, conversations, and actions taken in order to follow up and take corrective action as needed.\r\n\r\nWhat are the requirements and qualifications required for the job:\r\n\r\n* 1 to 5 Years experience in Approval Officer .\r\n* Bachelor's degree.\r\n* Advance in English .\r\n* Very Good problem-solving abilities.\r\n* Very Good in MS Office.\r\n* Very Good in Operation System.\r\n* Excellent analytical, communication, and decision-making skills are essential , organization, Familiarity with relevant regulations, policies, and procedures may be necessary."
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
job_posts %>% 
  mutate(experience = as.numeric(gsub(".*(\\d)+[ \\+]+years.*", "\\1", description)))
#> Warning: There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
#> ℹ In argument: `experience = as.numeric(gsub(".*(\\d)+[ \\+]+years.*", "\\1",
#>   description))`.
#> Caused by warning:
#> ! NAs introduced by coercion
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#>      id description                                                      exper…¹
#>   <int> <chr>                                                              <dbl>
#> 1     1 "Job Description *\r\n\r\nJob Title:\r\n\r\nPE Teacher\r\n\r\nS…      NA
#> 2     2 "مطلوب للتعيين فوراً محاسب فرع \r\nومشرف فروع مالي واداري لمجموع…        NA
#> 3     3 "RISAL\r\n\r\nWestern Province, Saudi Arabia\r\n\r\nPosted a da…      NA
#> 4     4 "The ideal candidate will lead the account development and pene…       2
#> 5     5 "Detailed Job Description:\r\n\r\n* Creating a Sales Action Pla…       3
#> 6     6 "Job Number 23052519 \r\nJob Category Housekeeping & Laundry \r…      NA
#> 7     7 "Job Description\r\n\r\nJob title:\r\n\r\nQuality Manager\r\n\r…       2
#> 8     8 "We are looking for a \" Approval Officer \" to join a \r\n\r\n…      NA
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​experience
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this is an amazing solution!
I spent hours writing that loop, so I really appreciate this solution.